# Get information from a Nested Json response using Python3 and jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm looking for help with itering through some JSON with python.

Currently I have a function which go to a URL which is a JSON API, get's the JSON and renders the result into a results.html. Within the results.html I'm using jinja2 and a for loop to get some information. What I can get is the information from _id and text, however what I want to do is get the information from the user section (see the JSON example below).

Results.py

```
@app.route("/results/")
def results():
catfactsURl = "https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/"
webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(catfactsURl)
if(webUrl.getcode() == 200):
    data = json.loads(webUrl.read())
    return render_template("results.html", data=data['all'], title="Results")
else:
    print("Received error, cannot parse results")
```

Results.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div>
   {% for datas in data %}
   <span>{{ datas['_id'] }}</span>
   <p>{{ datas['text'] }} </p>
   <p>{{ datas['user'] }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

{% endblock content %}

JSON response example

```
"all": [
{
  "_id": "58e0088b0aac31001185ed09",
  "text": "The world's largest cat measured 48.5 inches long.",
  "type": "cat",
  "user": {
    "_id": "58e007480aac31001185ecef",
    "name": {
      "first": "Kasimir",
      "last": "Schulz"
    }
  },
  "upvotes": 7,
  "userUpvoted": null
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data source is missing a 'user' key in one of the entries (58e008450aac31001185ecfd).  Get around it by checking for the presence of the user key first.

```
<div>
{% for datas in data %}
    <span>{{ datas['_id'] }}</span>
    <p>{{ datas['text'] }} </p>
    {% if 'user' in datas.keys() %}
        <p>{{ datas['user']['name']['first'] }} {{ datas['user']['name']['last'] }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: HI @FLSte, unfortunely, this didn't work as I was getting the following error when I tried to specfy the information (i.e <p>{{ datas['user']['name']['first'] }} {{ datas['user']['name']['last'] }}</p>) : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'user'

Comment: I looked at the data source.  1 record is missing the 'user' attribute.  Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @FLSte this worked for me. Just new learning this stuff so has really helped me get over a hill.